# Xcode: Failed Registering Bundle Identifier, how to pass level?

Tags: ios, xcode

Using Xcode 15.3. I have an existing app on App Store Connect

[image]

And my project is configured to use that bundle

[image]

And Xcode says I have certificates for that:

[image]

When doing archive, send to App Store for distribution I get:

[image]

which reads:

> Failed Registering Bundle Identifier
>
> The app identifier "net.phor.--Ballwatchkitapp" cannot be registered to your development team because it is not available. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.

> No profiles for 'net.phor.--Ball.watchkitapp' were found
>
> Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Store provisioning profiles matching 'net.phor.--
> Ball.watchkitapp'.

There are other other similar issues on SO, but they address earlier versions of Xcode. Each version of Xcode changes the way that it makes you bang your head against the wall, therefore those questions are not relevant to this one.

---

How do I pass this level?

Typically I try closing the project for a year, updating Xcode, making a new project, copying all the code in and trying again. This approach did not work this year.

On this machine last week I successfully signed/deployed another app on this same account with no problem.

If I change the bundle, Xcode wants me to create a new app in App Store Connect. I don't want to create a new app, I want to use that existing app.

Comment: In XCode accounts login, does your team has acces to the app ? @William Entriksen

Comment: It's your watch kit app bundle id that it is complaining about. Create a provisioning profile for it in your https://developer.apple.com account